# Use Python to Scape Data on website ends with aspx

Tags: web-scraping

https://blue.kingcounty.com/Assessor/eRealProperty/default.aspx

This is the website I want to scrape.

For example, I input 500 4TH AVE 
I just want to get Parcel Number and Lot size.

I was trying to edit the link

https://blue.kingcounty.com/Assessor/eRealProperty/search=5004THAVE.aspx

I think it did not work, please demonstrate. Thank you.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium for this crawl. When you hit that the link first time, it will ask to accept the terms and conditions then you need to click on the checkbox. After that, it will redirect to page, just pass the input to your current URL and read the HTML element using XPath or regex.

Comment: Do you mind sharing more details about how to implement it?